# text inside an art frame

Tags: css, image, background, border, margin

I'm getting frustrated here, trying to get my divs to line up properly!  I am trying to place my text inside an image of an art frame.  The html is:

```
<div id="frame">
<div id="songtext">
<p>lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
#frame {
background:url(images/gold-frame-trans-bg.png) no-repeat; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:0px;
width:650px;
height:750px;
}

#songtext {
width:336px;
height:410px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:140px; 
overflow:auto;
}
```

When I do it this way, the top of the image aligns with the top of the text, at 140px below the top of the screen.  But if I change 
    #songtext {margin-top:140px;}
 to
    #songtext {padding-top:140px;)
the text shows up in the right place, but the scrollbar still starts at the top of the page, interrupting the image.  And when I scroll up, the text scrolls over the image, rather than appearing to hide under it.  (Does this make sense?)
Here's the page if you'd rather see it visually:
http://studentaccess.emporia.edu/~asmith40/AVAwebsite/seemsimpossible.html

Comment: actual height = height propperty + padding + border, so padding makes the #songtext 140px higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#songtext {
 height: 410px;
 margin-left: 160px(or similar);
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-top: 140px;
 overflow: auto;
 position: absolute;
 width: 336px;
```

}

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it.  SO now I know that "position: absolute" nullifies the automatic centering command that normally works when you set "margin-left" and "margin-right" to "auto".  So in cases like these, I need the container div not only to hold the background image, but also to act as the centering element, so everything will automatically stay centered on the page.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems to me that you could do it with a only single DIV. But this is the pro task for the future ;)